# In angular is $pending only set on the form for $asyncValidators?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have an `ng-submit` function that is called when submitting a form.
I want to perform some action after any pending $asyncValidators are called.

```
if (myForm.$pending) {
    var pendingWatch = scope.$watch(function() {
         return myForm.$pending; }, function(pending) {
               if (!pending) {
                   pendingWatch();
                   performSubmit();
               }
         });
} else {
    performSubmit();    
}
```

The problem I am having is that myForm.$pending is always returning an object. Even with values that aren't `$asyncValidators` but rather custom `$validators` I added. This is not happening for all inputs.

How is is possible for the form to have pending validations that aren't even `$asyncValidators`? These "pending" validations never gets completed.

Answer (score 3):

No, actually, in my experience, $pending is also set on form, if any of your custom validators returns 'undefined' (even if there are not any asyncValidators present)

So to solve this issue, make sure all of your validators return true / false